# How to avoid get all relation in Entity Framework model

Tags: entity-framework, relationship

I'm developing a migration app and I'm having problems with OutOfMemory due to big relations that source model has.

Better explained with an example:

- EntityA has 6 relationships (EntityB, EntityC, EntityD...).
- EntityB has 8 relationships ...
- EntityB1 has 3 relationships ...

And goes on that way.

Then the problem is that when you try to get all information and do all the process, the app throws and OutOfMemory exception.

I would like to know if I can avoid some relationships, or in case that is not possible avoid all relationships. (programatically)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Turn off lazy loading, and 'include' only what you really need.

Comment: Lazy loading is only a problem if it's actually triggered. *If* it's triggered in the data migration process it means that the data is necessary and eager loading won't be the solution.

Comment: Please show more details of the migration process. It's not clear why you think it would help to "avoid some relationships" or whether that would even be possible (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching to disable Lazy loading.

> Lazy Loading means that entities will be automatically and transparently loaded when you first access property in query.

With EDMX you can disable it editing his properties (F4 on .edmx file).
[image]

With Code first, you can use this line :

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Now that you've disabled it, you'll have to include in your queries the relationships you need using :

```
dbContext.MyEntity.Include(p=> p.MyRelationProperty)
                  .Include(p=> p.MyOtherRelationProperty)
                  [...]
                  .ToList();
```

OR

```
dbContext.MyEntity.Include("MyRelationProperty")
                  .Include("MyRelationProperty.MySubRelationProperty")
                  .Include("MyOtherRelationProperty")
                  [...]
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you think lazy loading is the problem? See my comment under the question.

Comment: I think can be the solution, but I have to try it. One question more, it is possible to include.("x") or to .load() in a list of entities. I would like to include or to load after make the first search, to increase performance.

Comment: @GertArnold agree with you. Maybe it's for another reason. I test a solution who resolve 90% of cases. If it not resolves, i'll delete answer. @kartGIS not sure i understand your question, but yes it is possible to include a collection like `.Include("MyCollectionProperty")`

Comment: Sorry I've explained bad, but I solve that comment using dbContext.MyEntity.Include("MyRelationProperty")                  .Include("MyRelationProperty.MySubRelationProperty").Where(x=>x.something="yes").Include("MyOtherRelationProperty").ToList()

Comment: ok, @kartGIS if my anwser helps you, feel free to accept it checking the green tick thanks !

Comment: Sorry @GGO, my fault!  Yep your answer is good. I test it, and that is the problem. Thx!